# Perl Proc module running method keeps program hanged not returning back why?

Tags: perl, file, process, locking

PERL PROC Module running function never get exited - it keep running infinitely

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Proc::PID::File;

my %g_args = ( name => "temp", verify => 1, dir => "/home/username/");
print "Hello , world";
print Proc::PID::File->running(%g_args);
exit(0);
```

Even on CTRL + C its not being killed.

Its not even throwing any exception - where am I wrong.

I'm very beginner for PERL lang.

Comment: If I use dir => "/tmp" program works perfectly fine.

Comment: 1.`ps | grep 'script.pl'`

2. Take process id of the script, then finally,

3. `kill pid`

Comment: I've killed it several times and started too - problem OS is not able to acquire lock on that file.

Comment: Operating System is failed to acquire exclusive lock on file. :-(

Comment: The fact that `/tmp` works might be a clue. Is `/home/username` on a local file system or is it remotely mounted?

Comment: Its remotely mounted as an NFS file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File locking on NFS mounted disks is problematic, even at the best of times. [Proc::PID::File](https://metacpan.org/module/Proc%3a%3aPID%3a%3aFile) seems designed to operate on local filesystems (at least my perusal of the code doesn't indicate that it's taking the special care required to handle remote systems). Hanging on NFS problems is unfortunately typical of some NFS related problems. You will not be able to easily kill the process.

Is there some reason that you need to use the home directory? If you only need synchronization for jobs running on a single machine, `/tmp` should suffice. If you need to synchronize across multiple machines, then you should consider modules which are known to be more NFS safe, or use a client server model and avoid filesystems entirely. [CPAN](https://search.cpan.org) is full of solutions.